# Regex - Find the Shortest Match Possible

Tags: regex

### The Problem

Given the following:

```
\plain\f2 This is the first part of the note. This is the second part of the note. This is the \plain\f2\fs24\cf6{\txfielddef{\*\txfieldstart\txfieldtype1\txfieldflags144\txfielddataval44334\txfielddata 35003800380039000000}{\*\txfielddatadef\txfielddatatype1\txfielddata 340034003300330034000000}{\*\txfieldtext 20{\*\txfieldend}}{\field{\*\fldinst{ HYPERLINK "44334" }}{\fldrslt{20}}}}\plain\f2\fs24 part of the note.
```

I'd like to produce this:

```
\plain\f2 This is the first part of the note. This is the second part of the note. This is the third part of the note.
```

---

### What I've Tried

The example input/output is a *very simplified* version of the data I need to parse and it would be nice to have a way to parse the data programmatically. I have a PHP application and I've been trying to use regex to match the segments that are important and then filter out the parts of the string that aren't required. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
/\\plain.*?\\field{\\\*\\fldinst{ HYPERLINK "(.*?)" }}{\\fldrslt{(.*?)}}}}\\plain.*? /gm
```

regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ILLZU6/2

It almost matches what I want, but it but grabs the longest possible match instead of the shortest. I want it to match only one `\\plain` before the `\\field{...`. Maybe after the `\\plain`, I could match anything except for a space? How would I go about doing that?

I'm no regex expert, but my use-case really calls for it. (Otherwise, I'd just write code to handle everything.) Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the capture groups?

Comment: Yes, I use the capture groups in my PHP code for the following purposes: Group 1 - to import other linked records. Group 2 - to identify what all the gibberish should be replaced by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:(?!\\plain).)*` will match any string unless it contains a match for `\\plain`. Here's the regex implementing this:

```
/\\plain(?:(?!\\plain).)*\\field{\\\*\\fldinst{ HYPERLINK "(.*?)" }}{\\fldrslt{(.*?)}}}}\\plain.*? /gm
```

regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ILLZU6/5

---

Also, you can replace the space at the end with `(?: |$)` if you want to allow the end of the text to trigger it as well as a space:

```
/\\plain(?:(?!\\plain).)*\\field{\\\*\\fldinst{ HYPERLINK "(.*?)" }}{\\fldrslt{(.*?)}}}}\\plain.*?(?: |$)/gm
```

regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ILLZU6/4

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you! I ended up using the second option you suggested because you were right in that I wanted the end of the text to trigger a match as well.